# C# DATASET RELATIONS

Tags: c#

I have two table

```
Parent Table STUDENT ====> ID,NAME                 SqlCommand==>Select * from Student
Child  Table Lessons ====> ID,STUDENTID,LESSON     SqlCommand==>Select * from Lessons
```

I create DataRelation for two table with ID and StudentId

I add 2 datagridview to my form.

First Table `DataSource=Dataset.Relations[0].ParentTable;`

Second Table `DataSource=Dataset.Relations[0].ChildTable;`

its not working like relational.How can I MAke child table StudentId defaultvalue parent table ID value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second grid DataSource should be set to the DataSet.Relations[0] object.  In this case, everything will work properly.  Also, just found an MSDN article:

[Walkthrough: Creating a Master/Detail Form Using Two Windows Forms DataGridView Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8c0cxey.aspx)

Comment: thanks but not working.Do i not define child table or parent table?